# Top forest view with filter, can I include all children?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, top

If I'm using top in "forest" mode (V) and I restrict by PID (o PID=12345), can I also get top to show all the child processes in the same view?

Ubuntu, top from procps-ng version 3.3.9

Comment: Please tag your question with the operating system you are using and/or the version of top (`top -v`) you are using.